# Probabilities of avoiding for $28$ consecutive times the first place out of $6$, without cheating

Tags: probability

I'm concerned that the performance order at speech tournaments are not being randomly assigned.  What are the odds of the home team not getting the first performance slot in 14 categories with 6 performers in each round  and 2 rounds ?  So they'd have 28 chances to go first yet they don't.  In other words what are the odds of not rolling a 1 in 28 chances ?  Now it happens 2 years in a row

Answer (score 2):

If you roll a fair $6$-sided dice $28$ times, the probability of not rolling a $1$ is $$ (5/6)^{28} \approx 0.006. $$

The odds in favor of not rolling a $1$ are approximately $6$ to $994$.